# Flash dynamic input box @ and " symbol issue

Tags: flash, email, actionscript, input

Having a very strange issue with a few creative banners. On some computers when you type in an input box for an email field instead of the @ symbol you get the " symbol. It is almost as though the keyboard has the wrong language set. This isn't the case though, they are all se to UK.

I'm thinking it could be an issue with embedded fonts / charsets. Has anyone else ever had a similar issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also watch out if you are using wmode='transparent' messes up non-English keyboards.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that, had a similar issue with another project. Very random bug!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it always the way, when you post the question you find the answer!

If anyone has a similar issue make sure you have "Use device fonts" set with the dynamic input box.